# Rsync Wildcard Expansion Broken with SSH

Tags: ssh, rsync, wildcards

Ansible generates:

```
/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh 'ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -o User=ansible' --rsync-path="sudo rsync" --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' template.ephemeric.local:/home/*/bin/ /tmp/test/
```

I strip it down:

```
/usr/bin/rsync --rsh 'ssh -o User=ansible' template.ephemeric.local:/home/*/bin/ /tmp/test/
```

and get:

```
rsync: change_dir "/home/*/bin" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

This works:

```
/usr/bin/rsync --rsh ssh template.ephemeric.local:/home/*/bin/ /tmp/test/
receiving incremental file list
./
new4
sent 33 bytes  received 164 bytes  394.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

Now what on earth could this be? As soon as I add any SSH options it breaks wildcard expansion...

Any help/workarounds much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any chance it's a permissions issue?  The failed command is connecting as `User=ansible`, while the command that works is connecting using your username.  If you manually log in as the `ansible` user on `template.ephemeric.local`, what happens if you run `ls /home/*/bin`?

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing to do with the number of parameters to `--rsh`. It's just that your remote user `ansible` cannot see an expansion of `/home/*/bin/`

Here is a local example. I have at least one directory matching `/home/*/bin` but none matching `/home/*/bins`:

```
rsync --rsh 'ssh -o User=roaima' remotehost:/home/*/bin/ /tmp/bins/
skipping directory .

rsync --rsh 'ssh -o User=roaima' remotehost:/home/*/bins/ /tmp/bins/
rsync: change_dir "/home/*/bins" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1668) [Receiver=3.1.2]
```

The `skipping directory .` response in the first attempt is telling me that there was nothing to transfer - principally because I omitted to indicate that `rsync` should use recursion. The `--archive` or `--recursive` flags would be of use here.